# trouble checking CSS property with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to move a div by clicking a button and have an alert pop up when the top margin is a certain value. However, the alert only pops up after I am moving it away from the margin I want.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
$("input.down").click(function()
    $(".block").animate({"margin-top": "+=50px"});
    check();
});

$("input.up").click(function(){
    $(".block").animate({"margin-top": "-=50px"});
    check();
});

function check(){
    var top = $(".block").css("margin-top");

    if (top == "100px") {
        alert('top: ' + top + '\nyou have the right height');
    }
}
```

When I initially move the margin-top to 100px there is no alert, but once I move it away from there, there is an alert. Its like the check function if run first and then the div is animated. Is there a way to make it so it is animated first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("input.down").click(function() {
   $(".block").animate({"margin-top": "+=50px"}, function() { check(); });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked. I'm curious to know why putting check() inside of a function would allow the animation to happen first

Comment: in my code, `check()` is performed when the animation completes; but in your code, `check()` is performed just after the animation starts. in that case, as the animation is not completed, `check()` will find that the `<div>` is not at `100px`, so it won't alert message. but when you click it again, animation starts, `check()` runs, this time, message is alerted because the `<div>` is at `100px` in the last animation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("input.down").click(function(){
       $(".block").animate({"margin-top": "+=50px"}, {"complete": check});
    });
```

This should run the `check` function once the animation is complete.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, I'll do:

```
    $("input.down").click(function()
       var marginTop = $(".block").css("margin-top");
       $(".block").animate({"margin-top": marginTop + 50}, function() {
            check();
       });           
    });

   $("input.up").click(function(){
       var marginTop = $(".block").css("margin-top");
    $(".block").animate({"margin-top": marginTop - 50 }, function() {
            check();
       });          
    });

  function check(){
   var top = $(".block").css("margin-top");

   if (top == "100px") {
   alert('top: ' + top + '\nyou have the right height');
  };}
```